The roles of TCS and swarm intelligence in cognition and other phenomena
Is there any ongoing research on the intersection of TCS with fields such as cognitive science (maybe shedding light onto how humans ideate and reason in specific manners such as in philosophy and Mathematics),in such a way that TCS would pave avenue for elucidating the manners in wich the underlying mechanisms could be analogous to other Computational/algorithmic structure found some other phenomena(an instance would be related phenomena studied by swarm intelligence)? I'd appreciate any paper or book suggested.
